# Unexpected character '⇒' React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As a newbie to React.js I am playing around with some React.js code and I like it very much, but do not understand why I get some error on the follow syntax -->  {this.state.data.map((person, i) ⇒ )}. According to an online tutorial this should work, so that makes me confusing. If I remove the EcmaScript 2015 arrow syntax (⇒) I will get another error in this syntax..

```js
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
 constructor() {
  super();

  this.state = {
   data:
   [
    {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "Foo", 
     "age": "12"
    },
    {
     "id": 2,
     "name": "Bar",
     "age": "30"
    },
    {
     "id": 3,
     "name": "Baz",
     "age": "40"
    }
   ] 
  }
 } 

 render() {
  return (
   <div> 
   <Header/>
            <table>
               <tbody>
                  {this.state.data.map((person, i) ⇒ <TableRow key = {i} data = {person} />)}
               </tbody>
            </table>
   </div>
  )
 }
}

class Header extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <div>
    <h1>Header</h1>
   </div>
  )
 }
}

class TableRow extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <tr>
    <td>{this.props.data.id}</td>
    <td>{this.props.data.name}</td>
    <td>{this.props.data.age}</td>
   </tr>
  );
 }
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_components.htm check Stateful example

Comment: Are you using a general purpose editor instead of one specifically for code? You definitely don't want your editor replacing `1/2` with `½`, single or double quotes with smart quotes (`“”`), or in this case, arrow functions (`=>`) with the arrow symbol (`⇒`)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you should use `=>` this operator, not the symbol. It's a equal sign and a greater than sign.

The code was likely formatted when published, but instead `⇒` it's `=>`!

Comment: Thanks, never thought the answer was that simple.